# install xclip on a linux computer with no root access?

Tags: linux, bash, installation

I am trying to install xclip on a linux computer with no root access, I downloaded, decompressed and run `./configure` but got an error for a missing library:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/bin/xclip/
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
[...]
checking for XmuClientWindow in -lXmu... no
configure: error: *** libXmu not found ***
```

How can I get overcome this error and install xclip?

Answer (score 1):

**You need the `libXmu` library** – if it's already installed, you're probably missing the development headers (`/usr/include/X11/Xmu` and others), which many distributions require to be installed separately.

You will have to either compile `libXmu` the same way manually, or obtain the `libxmu-dev` or `libxmu-devel` package and extract it into, say, `~/usr`.

Afterwards, set:

```
export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/usr/lib"
```

You may also need:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$HOME/usr/share/pkgconfig"
```

Also take a look at `xsel`, which does pretty much the same thing but requires less library dependencies.

---

Note: `--prefix ~/bin/xclip` will result in ugly paths such as `~/bin/xclip/bin/xclip` and `~/bin/xclip/share/man/man1/xclip.1`. Something like `--prefix ~/usr` will give nicer results.

This is especially worth noting when installing libraries; it is much easier to compile a program when all its libraries are in `--prefix ~/usr`, rather than each having its own `--prefix`.

Comment: It seems there are xmu headers there: ls /usr/include/X11/Xmu
Atoms.h    CloseHook.h   CurUtil.h   DisplayQue.h  Editres.h   Error.h     Initer.h  Misc.h     StdSel.h   WidgetNode.h  Xct.h
CharSet.h  Converters.h  CvtCache.h  Drawing.h     EditresP.h  ExtAgent.h  Lookup.h  StdCmap.h  SysUtil.h  WinUtil.h     Xmu.h

Comment: It could be that it's just too old (the error message actually says that `XmuClientWindow` does not exist in libXmu; it is unclear as to whether the entire libXmu or just that single symbol is missing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround (requires gvim and bash):

```
# My workaround for not having xsel or xclip
function get_clip() {
    file=/tmp/$USER/clipboard_contents.txt
    /bin/rm -f $file
    # Help from:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23237529/120681
    gvim $file -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -c 'set nomore' +'normal "*P' +'wq'
    cat $file
}
```

Which then can be used [like](https://gist.github.com/stephenmm/1b65227bba176e220d23e1ba849b8193):

```
clip=$( get_clip )
```